# How can i calculate time of redrawing UIButton when i change it size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to calculate time of button redrawing when I change size. I want to know which is redrawing faster - UIButton, or UIView. I've tried to inherit UIButton class and override `drawRect` method where calculate performance time. But that method hadn't been called when I change button size. Ideas?

Comment: This is called "premature optimization" Quote: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth. Don't do it, except for fun. BTW ,a `UIButton` *is* a `UIView`: `UIButton`inherits from `UIView`.

Comment: i just need to know how much it takes to redraw button

Comment: The time to redraw will be different for each type of device and also different for simulator for different computers.

Comment: I know it. But I need to know how much it takes on my device - iphone 4s. Can i calculate that time?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the time for the instructions to execute you can try the below

```
startTime = 0;
endTime = 0;
elapsedTime = 0;
elapsedTimeNano = 0;

mach_timebase_info_data_t timeBaseInfo;
mach_timebase_info(&timeBaseInfo);

startTime = mach_absolute_time();


//Redraw UIButton/UIView Code

elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
elapsedTimeNano = elapsedTime * timeBaseInfo.numer / timeBaseInfo.denom;
```

Note: You need to import this `#import <mach/mach_time.h>`

Hope this helps